# WebView can't handler url which contains chinese?

Tags: android, webview

I am just gonna upload a file whose name contains chinese using the hiding method of webview like this below:

```
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                    WebViewActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        }

        // For Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg,
                String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
                    WebViewActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        // For Android 4.1
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"),
                    WebViewActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

        }
    });
```

This code is good to run, and I can upload file successfully without Chinese characters. It came to be a problem when I choose a file whose name has Chinese characters,then I get the callback like this:

```
if (null == mUploadMessage) return;    
                    Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();  
                    mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(***result***);    
                    mUploadMessage = null;
```

This result is the Type of URI, and its path contains Chinese, then the problem occurs and the WebView gives an exception like:
`net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`,I tried to format the path of the Uri with utf-8,but it doesnot work.

Has anyone met with this problem? I have been troubling about this for 3 days,Who can help me,Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can change Chinese to iso8859 character or others through w3c